# Will it be useful changing the code with the below approach?

Tags: apex

I was looking at a class where I could see the class has implemented vlocity interface.
There are five different methods in the class where this initialization is being written.

```
public void method MethodOne(){
    vlocity_cmt.CpqAppHandler appHandler = new vlocity_cmt.CpqAppHandler();
}

public void method methodTwo(){
    vlocity_cmt.CpqAppHandler appHandler = new vlocity_cmt.CpqAppHandler();
}
```

So I decided to change the code using the below approach.

```
public vlocity_cmt.CpqAppHandler appHandler{
    get{
        if(appHandler == NULL){
            return new vlocity_cmt.CpqAppHandler();
        }
        return appHandler;
    }
    set;
}

public void method MethodOne(){
  appHandler.invoke();
}

public void method methodTwo(){
   appHandler.invoke();
}
```

I want to experience to make the code better. I would like to know if this approach will help me?

Comment: Null coalescing op is your friend - `get { return appHandler ?? new vlocity_cmt.CpqAppHandler(); }`

Comment: @identigral That version is wasteful, because it never stores the results of construction. I suggested therefore `get { return appHandler = appHandler ?? new vlocity_cmt.CpqAppHandler(); }`

Comment: @sfdcfox Whether it's wasteful depends on the call profile (how many calls/when/etc), lazy loading is always a trade-off

Comment: @identigral Forgetting the assignment misses the point of using lazy loading, because you are no longer lazy loading if you call the constructor more than once. In this case, the difference is trivial, but imagine: `public Account record { get { return record ?? [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1]; } }` and you should immediately realize why it's a problem.

Comment: @sfdcfox Our top-level comment was not intended to be an implementation of lazy loading

Answer (score 4):

While "better" is usually pretty subjective, what you're attempting to do here is a pattern called "lazy loading" or "lazy initialization".

You don't quite have it right though. You need to set the value of your `appHandler` property in the getter (otherwise it will always be null, and you'll end up calling the constructor again on the next call).

```java
public vlocity_cmt.CpqAppHandler appHandler{
    get{
        if(appHandler == null){
            // set appHandler's value so we only execute this constructor once for
            //   this object instance's lifetime
            appHandler = new vlocity_cmt.CpqAppHandler();
        }

        return appHandler;
    }
    set;
}
```

This is a useful pattern when the constructor takes a considerable amount of resources (CPU Time, queries, etc...) so you aren't incurring that cost multiple times. Be careful if that handler class contains internal state though. You could unwittingly work yourself into some bizarre errors if its maintaining state but the client code assumes that it's stateless.

In terms of "does it reduce the amount of typing/duplication in my code", it's probably a wash. You're adding 5-6 lines of code in one place to save some typing on 5 lines of code elsewhere (no actual reduction in LoC).

If anything, the benefit here would probably be in getting you closer to *dependency injection* (i.e. if you have a method in a class that uses/depends on a thing, you should pass that thing into the class/method rather than creating it inside of the class/method that uses it). Dependency injection makes it a lot easier to test things in isolation.

Comment: But this will help me to improve the cpu time as it not not gonna initialize again  and again.  I was trying to improvise the code by making it faster, less resource consumption

Comment: @NBR That's almost certainly a micro-optimization. Lazy initialization can help mitigate expensive constructors, but in your case here the difference is unlikely to be measurable at all. In my experience, the path to "good code" is mostly in making code somewhat DRY (don't repeat yourself) and easily testable.

Answer (score 1):

There is a non-zero cost in CPU time when using lazy loading. That is, it costs to check every time if the variable has already been loaded.

You can save a small amount of CPU using the new null coalescing operator:

```
get {
  return appHandler = appHandler ?? new vlocity_cmt.CpqAppHandler();
}
```

Or, if you know each method will need it, just initialize it in a constructor or with inline assignment:

```
public vlocity_cmt.CpqAppHandler appHandler = new vlocity_cmt.CpqAppHandler();
```